How to get the country name on click event on the country in Highmaps (Highcharts) with the connected map "OpenStreetMap"?
It would be great if you could help me with the example.
my examle

Unfortunately, OpenStreetMap tiles don't inherently provide country data, so it's not possible to get country name when clicking a country. Still there's a great official Highcharts demo showing rich information when clicking the country: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0hs5Lzco/

Unfortunately, your example is not suitable, I need a detailed map with street names and house numbers. Maybe it can be implemented on some other map similar to "OpenstreetMap"?

Maybe Highcharts/HighMaps has functionality to display streets and houses, or maybe Highcharts/HighMaps has another detailed world map with streets and houses? maybe GoogleMaps will do and your have an demo example?

Sorry, but I'm afraid it's not possible.
